# Unable to locate element in onPrepare of protractor.conf.js

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I'm writing e2e-tests for an AngularJS-App with `Jasmine` and `protractor`. I  have a problem with the `onPrepare`-function in the protractor.conf.js.
If I do following in a `beforeAll` it works fine:

```
browser.get('/login');
element(by.id('username')).sendKeys('John');
```

but if I do this in `onPrepare`

```
browser.driver.get('https://localhost:9000/login');
browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username')).sendKeys('John');
```

I get this error:

```
NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element:    {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="username"]"}
```

Any hints?

P.S.: In the protractor docu there is link to this example that I used as pattern: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/withLoginConf.js

Comment: can you post your config file as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are using "*browser.driver*" format? We should follow that format only for Non-Angular applications not for Angular application. Just try same codes as you tried in *beforeAll()* in *onPrepare()* as well. It will work.

```
onPrepare: function () {
      browser.get('https://localhost:9000/login');
      element(by.id('username')).sendKeys('John');
},
```

Even if it does not work, implement browser.wait() for complete page to load.